# What one forms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be extended to $\mathbb{S}^n$?

Tags: differential-geometry

So $\mathbb{S}^n-p$ where $p$ is a single point can be identified with stereographic projection. Say we define a one form (or vector field) on $\mathbb{R}^n$. When would this "fail" to produce one on $\mathbb{S}^n$. Usually when extending one-forms on open neighbourhoods there are issues coming from cohomology and so on. But since a point is cohomologically trivial, I guess this shouldn't be a problem here. But I think maybe you have to put some conditions "at infinity" for your one-form?

Comment: If you use coordinates on $\mathbb S^n$ that include $p$ (e.g. stereographic projection from the opposite pole), then this becomes the problem of extending a form from $U\setminus p$ to $U$ for an open subset $U$ of Euclidean space; so you should just have to check that the form and all its derivatives (up to whatever order of smoothness you require) have limits at $p$. If you like, you can then do the change of variables back to phrase this as limits "at infinity".